# How to delete in kotlin data from Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I have problem with delete data from my Firebase Data. I have application who add name and surname to database and button which delete this.

How i can implement function deleteUser?
User click Button and delete row with this data on applcation.

```
   val database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
    myRef = database.getReference("Users")
    recycler_view.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(applicationContext, 1)

    submitdataBTN.setOnClickListener {
        val name = nameInput.text.toString()
        val surname = surnameInput.text.toString()
        val firebaseIntent = DatabaseRow(name, surname)
        myRef.child("${Date().time}").setValue(firebaseIntent)
    }
```

**Add users on row**

```
     myRef.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
        override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {
            TODO("Not yet implemented")
        }

        override fun onDataChange(databaseSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            listofItems = ArrayList()
            for (i in databaseSnapshot.children) {
                val newRow = i.getValue(DatabaseRow::class.java)
                listofItems.add(newRow!!)
            }
            setupAdapter(listofItems)
        }
    })
```

[This is my UI and when user click delete then remove data from row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bvmyT.png)

How can implement delete data function?

[image: My database]

Comment: In the screenshot you shared: which node is for the current user? And how would I (and your code) know that?

Comment: when you click on speicific row you can get the node reference of that particular user and then call the database operation of single valuevent and set the value null. it will delete that particular row